# Receive and send XML PHP

Tags: php, xml

I receive XML by CURL: `$retValue = curl_exec($ch);` 
And I wand to send with XML to JavaScript

I try `echo $retValue` but it's not XML

How can I send XML to JavaScript from PHP?

Comment: What do you mean by `it's not XML`?

Comment: $retValue may be XML, but if you are just outputting it and displaying it in the browser, your browser may be displaying it incorrectly. Try viewing source in the browser.

Comment: I mean - my js script can't read with XML - http_request.responseXML

Comment: I see: 1 Assisted/Independent Living 123. but i need - This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<search>
<location id="6179" client_id="149">
<site>1</site>

Comment: Are you viewing the source of the page (Ctrl-U in many browsers)? The tags may very well be hidden from your view. use the htmlspecialchars function if you want to see it with the < and > visible

Comment: alert(http_request.responseXML) = &lt;?xml version... And can't read XML